# Removing Duplicate Entries in a ROOT TTree

Tags: root-framework

I have three `.root` files that I need to merge together. Normally I would use `hadd` to merge the files, but the files contain duplicate entries which I need to remove. I can't just delete the duplicated entries because TTrees are read-only. Is there a simple way to merge the files while ensuring that only unique entries are saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to find a way to produce histograms that contain only unique entries using `TEntryList`. This allows you to specify which tree entries you wish to use. In my case, each entry has an event number which identifies it. So, I generated an entry list with the entry numbers corresponding to only unique event numbers.

```
set<int> eventIds; // keep track of already seen event numbers
int EVENT;
int nEntries = tree->GetEntries();

tree->SetBranchAddress("EVENT",&EVENT); // grab the event number from the tree

TEntryList *tlist = new TEntryList(tree); // initialize entry list for 'TTree* tree'

// loop over the entries in 'tree'
for (int j = 0; j < nEntries; ++j)
{
    tree->GetEvent(j);

    // if we have not seen this event yet, add it to the set
    // and to the entry list
    if (eventIds.count(EVENT) == 0)
    {
        eventIds.insert(EVENT);
        tlist->Enter(j,tree);
    }
}

// apply the entry list to the tree
tree->SetEntryList(tlist);

// histogram of the variable 'var' will be drawn only with the
// entries specified by the entry list.
tree->Draw("var");
```

Comment: This is the only way I've ever been able to do this, so I think this is the right answer.